# LAMP blank page, no errors

Tags: lamp

This week a symptom has developed on a web site that has been running for several years. Monday evening we start getting reports of occasional blank pages returned without any delay.  Refreshing the page would get a valid page.  Over the course of three hours this got worse until even multiple refreshes no longer display anything.  top, mytop and apachetop all look normal: CPU% is at 4.3%; apache handling 84 requests (2.8/sec); mysql qps  is 8. php_errors.log showed nothing.

All of this looks normal.  And there is the issue - I have no idea what else to look at to find out what is wrong.  The PHP error_reporting is set to E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE.  Rebooting the system helps for about 12 hours.  We are going to reboot at 3am to mitigate the symptoms, but this does nothing to solve the problem.

Any ideas?  All are welcome, 'cause I am stumped.

---

[3/6/2014] **A new development...**

I created an extremely simple php page to help diagnose.  It too fails and it may point to the cause.

The page sets error_reporting to E_ALL, calls phpinfo() and then displays the current session values.  When the problem occurs the page still runs but $_SESSION is empty.  After a few page reloads the values come back.

I tried including the code here, but even putting it in pre tags it gets interpreted and doesn't display.

Comment: What does access log says when it goes blank? It could be a temporary memory spike and a particular worker unable to reserve enough space (and gives up showing blank)

Comment: There were 125 entries during the minute I observed the white screen - just a bunch of Get/Post items.  Is there something I should look for?  I see no errors.